# Windows 7 Machine and Exchange 2007 Connection

Tags: windows-7, exchange-2007, outlook-2007

I am using a Windows 7 machine which has Outlook 2007 client installed and connected to
an Exchange Server 2007.

When I lock the screen for a few minutes then lock back in when I get to my desk I
get the "Connect to exchange" dialog box prompting me to enter my password again?

Is there any reason for this, and how can this be fixed? It did not happen on  my 
old XP machine.

Comment: No not using XP anymore. I am using Windows 7. I had no probs with XP previously. I started having this issue when I moved to Win7. All of Exchange is in one child domain and that is where I log into.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a power savings settins setup on the NIC Card when you lock the computer for few minutes.

change the power savings on the computer and see it that will work.

I assume this is the issue since you said that you are walking away for few minutes.

Comment: I agree.  It sounds like a "sleep" issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Connect to exchange" usually appears when you are not logged into the domain that Exchange is on. Can you log into the domain (where Exchange is a part of) prior to starting Outlook?

Comment: I am logged into the domain and have just locked the screen. Please read the baove again. Unless you imply locking the screen locks you out?

Comment: Locking the screen does not log off from the domain. Is the domain that you log into the same domain that the Exchange server(s)/infrastructure is on? If your login domain and the Exchange domain is not the same, then you will run into the additional login prompt when starting Outlook. Did you log into a different domain with your XP system?